# Why the first div content adding extra padding/margin to the top?

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="background-color: #f6f6f6; white-space: nowrap; padding-bottom: 3px; height: 270px;">
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: white; margin-right: 3px; width: 286px; height: 267px;">
    asdf<br />asdsd
  </div><div style="display: inline-block; background-color: white; margin-right: 3px; width: 286px; height: 267px">
  asdf<br />dsasdf<br />asdsd
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: white; width: 286px; height: 267px">
    asdf<br />dsasdf<br />asdsd
  </div>
</div>
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mdogancay/gbk350av/

why is this happening?

Comment: That is not padding/margin.. You didn't vertical align them `vertical-align:top;`

Comment: @Stender thanks for your answer, why browsers aligns divs by it's content? without div content (and without vertical-align) divs perfectly aligned to the each other?

Comment: This is related to "how baseline is calculated" baseline is the initial value of vertical-align. You should read CSS 2.2 specification, and in particular: normal-flow, block-formatting and inline formatting of inline-level boxes. here is the reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you'r using `inline-block` preperty in each 3 `div`. And Unlike the first `div`, other `divs` have 3 lines and the `inline-block` property tries to adjust first `div` according to the row of other `divs`.To solve this problem, use `<br />` at the beginning of the first `div's` row

As follows

```
<div style="background-color: #f6f6f6; white-space: nowrap; padding-bottom: 3px; height: 270px;">

  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: white; margin-right: 3px; width: 286px; height: 267px;">
    <br />asdf<br />asdsd
  </div>

  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: white; margin-right: 3px; width: 286px; height: 267px">
    asdf<br />dsasdf<br />asdsd
  </div>

  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: white; width: 286px; height: 267px">
    asdf<br />dsasdf<br />asdsd
  </div>
</div>
```

OR
Add `display: flex` property to parent `div` (without adding extra `<br />`)

```
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: white; margin-right: 3px; width: 286px; height: 267px;">
    asdf<br />asdsd
  </div>

  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: white; margin-right: 3px; width: 286px; height: 267px">
    asdf<br />dsasdf<br />asdsd
  </div>

  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: white; width: 286px; height: 267px">
    asdf<br />dsasdf<br />asdsd
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `display:flex` to the parent/outer div and that should take care of the padding issue.

```css
#outer {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  height: 270px;
  display:flex;
  
}

#div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 3px;
  width: 286px;
  height: 267px;
  
}

#div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 3px;
  width: 286px;
  height: 267px;
}

#div3 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  width: 286px;
  height: 267px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="div1">
    div1-line1<br />div1-line2
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    div2-line1<br />div2-line2<br />div2-line3
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
    div3-line1<br />div3-line2<br />div3-line3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but i am trying to learn the logic here. Why browsers doing that?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you add height to each div with display: inline-block. Try to remove it and add float: left for each div. It'll work
[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKDiQ.png)

Comment: thanks. Like i said to the @Stender, without div's content there is no problem. I wanna understand the browser's behaviour here. Why divs aligning by it's content?

Comment: There are default values for CSS with the browser . check [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp). Div has display: block attribute by default.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the default 'vertical-alignment' attribute of HTML elements.
You can read more about it here:
https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/
and see some working examples here: https://dabblet.com/gist/2422174

basically, if you add "vertical-alignment : top" to the rouge div-element, it should be ok :)